# NHibernate Join Table with Non Primary Key

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I am trying to do a one to one join with 2 tables using non-primary fields.
I have 2 tables in the DB.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Branch](
[BranchID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Branch_Name] [nvarchar](100) NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Salesman](
[SalesmanID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[BranchID] [int] NOT NULL,
[First_Name] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[Last_Name] [nvarchar](30) NULL)
```

I basically need the Branch Name whenever I retrieve a row from the salesman table.
I thought I could add a join in the Salesman.hbm.xml file.

```
<join table="dbo.Branch">
  <key column="BranchID" />
  <property lazy="true"   update="false" insert="false"     not-null="false"  type="String" name="Branch_Name" />
</join>
```

This did not work because nHibernate always created a join with the primary key. I read some other posts and they suggested using a view for situations like this. So I created a view like so:

```
create view dbo.VIEW_Salesman As
SELECT a.[SalesmanID], a.[BranchID], a.[First_Name],a.[Last_Name],
(select [Branch_Name] FROM [dbo].[Branch] WHERE BranchID= a.[BranchID]) As Branch_Name
FROM [dbo].[Salesman] as a
```

The above view actually works but is there a better solution when you want to join 2 tables using non-primary fields?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and advice,
Have a great day!

Comment: Wouldn't the relationship Branch Has Many Salesman and Salesman References ( <many-to-one name="Branch" />   Branch work for you? The Salesman entity can refer to the Branch object directly.

Comment: @WorldIsRound: +1 Good idea! I haven't even thought of it for a second in my answer! =)

Comment: Hi WorldlsRound can you elaborate on your <many-to-one name="Branch" /> solution. Do I place the <many-to-one> tag in the salesman mapping file and <one-to-many> in the branch mapping file? I don't understand how this would like nhiberate know to match BranchID.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use Dependancy Injection which actually has nothing to do with NHibernate, and would definitely force a change in your mapping file, or perhaps use a named query in the NHibernate configuration file.

Besides, I just thought that you perhaps could use composite mapping while using Dependancy Injection.

```
Salesman s = new Salesman(branchInstance)
```

So you should have a Branch property within your Salesman class that could allow you to know the branch name to which this salesman belongs. Otherwise, simply have a BranchName property which would actually return the `branchInstance.Name` property value.

See the following for Component Mapping using NHibernate:

1. [NHibernate Mapping -](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/08/nhibernate-mapping-ltcomponentgt.aspx) ;
2. [NHibernate - Chapter 7 - Component Mapping](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-7-component-mapping/1nr4enxv3dpeq/10#);
3. [NHibernate Reference Documentation](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html).

Or if you prefer to make it as a view using NHibernate, perhaps a named query should do it with less of a change:

1. [16.2. Named SQL queries](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-namedqueries).

Hope this helps! Do not hesitate to ask further details, I'll be pleased to assist you furhter if I can! =)